# How to access component value from another component with Angular 7

Tags: angular

I used this code to access the 'address' value from component, StripeComponent, to CreditCardComponent.  I get an empty value for address instead of the actual value in StripeComponent

Here is my child code in CreditCardComponent:

```js
import { StripeComponent} from '../stripe/stripe.component';

@Component({
  providers: [StripeComponent],
  selector: 'app-creditcard',
  templateUrl: './creditcard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./creditcard.component.css']
})
export class CreditCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() address : Address;
  @Input('address') ccAddress: Address;

  constructor(private creditCardService: CreditCardService,

  public stripeScriptTag: StripeScriptTag) {
    this.stripeScriptTag.setPublishableKey( this.publishableKey )
    this.ccAddress = this.creditCardComponent.ccAddress;
    console.log('this is the ccAddress', this.ccAddress);
}
```

This is the parent code in StripeComponent

```js
public address =
new Address(
  {
    name:"",
    address_city: "",
    address_line1: "",
    address_line2: "",
    address_state: "",
    address_zip: "",
    address_country: ""
  }
)
```

This is the Stripecomponent.html code, there is no html for creditcardcomponent.html

```
<div class = form>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitAddress()"  class="address" >

    <mat-form-field class="name-width-height">
      <input matInput name="name" 
       type="text" required [(ngModel)]="address.name"
     >
     <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Name</mat-placeholder>
    </mat-form-field>


       <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary"class="btn 
     address_form">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code if the problem is not solved!

Comment: Why are you even trying to have a component as input, and in your code, you are trying to use input on the component itself.

Comment: @AJT_82  Thanks, I realized that an corrected the code, 
  @Input() stripeComponent : StripeComponent;
  @Input('address') ccAddress: Address;

Comment: Anyway, you don't `Input` a component.

Comment: @AJT_82 I am following this example that does input a component https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I would like to know where exactly you see that a component is set as `@Input()` :D

Comment: oops you are right, Hero is not a component thanks,  this line ' @Input() hero: Hero;'

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it was that ;) Well, but yes, component are not set as inputs. So really, what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I have an address defined in the stripecomponent that I want access to in the creditcardcomponent

Comment: then `@Input('address') ccAddress: Address;` should be enough... if you have the child tag looking like this: `<app-creditcard [ccAddress]="the address variable here"></app-creditcard>` and remove the component as provider in your child :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I added this '  @Input('address') ccAddress: Address;'  when I console log ccAddress it is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are not used as inputs, you just pass the variable to your child component, so your parent template should look like:

```
<app-creditcard [ccAddress]="address"></app-creditcard>
```

In your child component, mark that as input as you have. That will be like Sajeetharan mentioned available in `OnInit` (or `OnChanges`).

Also remove the `providers: [StripeComponent]` from your child component.

Here is a sample: [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ensriq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: What an outstanding answer.  You made my day.  AJT, I totally understand how to import variables from one component to another.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of accessing in the constructor use ngOninit life cycle, **`@Input`** data will be available in **`ngOnInit`**

```
export class CreditCardComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(){
        this.ccAddress = this.creditCardComponent.ccAddress;
        console.log('this is the ccAddress', this.ccAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get this error now, "CreditCardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ccAddress' of undefined"  Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: which means CreditCardComponent is null . use ngIf on parent component

Comment: I think I should change my syntax to:  
  @Input() stripeComponent : StripeComponent;
  @Input('address') ccAddress: Address;

But I don't get this.stripeComponent.ccAddress .... in intellisense.